# Remove fields that are null or 0 in a StructType

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb

I am creating an aggregation with some fields and some of these fields can have a 0 or null values (I can keep null or change it to 0 depending on what works). This finally gets written to dynamodb. The reason I want to remove these null fields is to meet the record_size requirements on the dynamodb.

```
df.withColumn("phone_nos", struct(
  col("address"),
  col("home_number"),
  col("cell_number"),
  col("work_number"),
  .groupBy("name")
  .agg(collect_set(col("phone_nos")).alias("phone_nos_by_address"))
```

Each customer can have multiple addresses, but not necessarily all the phone numbers in that address.

I have tried to use `to_json` while that does remove the null fields, the consumer of ddb cannot read as a json string. I need a way to keep the map structure but remove the null fields.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share a bit more about how you construct your `putItem` input? Which SDK are you using?

Comment: I am using Glue  etl connector to write to DDB from my glue job. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-dynamodb